# In SQL, Compare Two Text Columns in Two Different Databases

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

SQL newb here.

I'm trying to use a UNION to compare some text type columns (thought this would be the easiest way):

```
SELECT 
      ResultText 
FROM [db1].[dbo].tblTransactions 
WHERE GWClientID = 122 AND Created > DATEADD(YEAR, -3, GETDATE())
UNION 
SELECT 
      ResultText 
FROM [db2].[dbo].tblTransactions 
WHERE GWClientID = 122 AND Created > DATEADD(YEAR, -3, GETDATE())
```

However I get the error:

> The data type text cannot be used as an operand to the UNION,
>   INTERSECT or EXCEPT operators because it is not comparable.

Why does this happen? What I use `UNION ALL`.I don't get the error but that's not what I want.

Why don't text types work and how can I compare the text columns?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try `cast(ResultText as varchar(max))`. I actually can't remember if that cast works though (and you didn't say which version of SQL Server either). Using a union isn't really a great way to do comparisons though.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that. It's across two sql servers (versions 11.0.3 and 10.0.55). Yes, probably not the best way. Just easy for a newb like me.

Comment: That cast did it Shawn! Thanks!

Comment: Also if anyone knows how to do this without a UNION I'd appreciate it.

Comment: What is wrong with a union ?   How can you be going across two sql servers with a 3 part name?

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the columns by joining them using `RIGHT JOIN` and assigning common fields for each query with the `ROW_NUMBER()`.
Note: I used `MS SQL SERVER 2012`

```
SELECT A.ResultText, B.ResultText FROM
(
SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ResultText) AS row,
      ResultText 
FROM [db1].[dbo].tblTransactions 
WHERE GWClientID = 122 AND Created > DATEADD(YEAR, -3, GETDATE())
)AS A 
RIGHT JOIN
(
SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ResultText) AS row,
      ResultText 
FROM [db2].[dbo].tblTransactions 
WHERE GWClientID = 122 AND Created > DATEADD(YEAR, -3, GETDATE())
)AS B 
ON A.row=B.row
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks! I'll have to do a bit of research to understand it but I think I get the general idea.

Comment: Then, You'll just need to accept my answer to close your question. Thanks.

Comment: Actually I ran this in my environment and the query returns nothing. I know  (using a data compare tool) that there are some differences. Do you know why this would be?

Answer (score 0):

Kind of assumes each "subquery" only returns a single row. Not sure how you're planning to use this information though.

```
select
    case
        when A.ResultText = B.ResultText then 'Same'
        else 'Not the same'
    end as Comparison
from
    (
    SELECT cast(ResultText as varchar(max)) as ResultText
    FROM db1.dbo.tblTransactions 
    WHERE GWClientID = 122 AND Created > DATEADD(YEAR, -3, GETDATE())
    ) as A,
    (
    SELECT cast(ResultText as varchar(max)) as ResultText
    FROM db2.dbo.tblTransactions 
    WHERE GWClientID = 122 AND Created > DATEADD(YEAR, -3, GETDATE())
    ) as B
```

You could also do an `INNER JOIN ON A.ResultText = B.ResultText` if you only want values(/pairs) that match up.